# C++ Time Limit Not Working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this program that is supposed to end and print a message if the user does not enter an input within a few seconds. But right now the time limit does not seem to be working although my code seems logical. (The time does not go off if the user does not enter anything) Why is that?

```
int userInput = 0;
int now = time(0);
int later = 0;
int elapsed = 0;
do {
    later = time(0);
    elapsed = later - now;
    cout << "Enter number" <<endl;
    cin >> userInput;   
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case 1: 
         elapsed = 0;
         break; 
    }

} while (elapsed < 4 && !_kbhit()); 


if (elapsed == 4)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Too Slow!! Now You're on the Menu!";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No warranty offered, but if using `_kbhit` is part of the solution, then you may want to attempt reading only if you detect some keyboard acrivity.

```
int userInput = 0;
int now = time(0);
int later = 0;
int elapsed = 0;

cout << "Enter number" <<endl;

do {
    later = time(0);
    elapsed = later - now;
    if(_kbhit()) { // we **may** have some input
        cin >> userInput;
        // this is useless for timing purposes!!
        // A simple `break` should suffice.
        switch(userInput)
        {
           case 1: 
             elapsed = 0;
           break; 
        }
    }

} while (elapsed < 4); 


if (elapsed == 4)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Too Slow!! Now You're on the Menu!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good, although it will stop checking the timer as soon as the user hits the first key, which may or may not be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @JasonC "which may or may not be what the OP is looking for." The "the user does not enter an input" in the question is ambiguous - "provide complete input" vs "starting to do something about that input".

Comment: Yes. "which may or not be what the OP is looking for" == "the ... question is ambiguous". Glad we're on the same page. If you want, I can think of even more equivalent phrases, and we can go back and forth saying the same thing. First one to run out of ways to say "the question is unclear" loses.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `operator>>` waits until input has been entered. Full stop.

```
cin >> userInput;
```

At this point, because standard input is an interactive terminal, the program pauses until something is typed in. Whether it takes minutes, hours, or days. Either the program is killed, or something gets typed in followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. There are no other outcomes.

Just because there's some other code in the program that sets some kind of a timer, or whatnot, doesn't change this basic fact. Nothing else is going to execute until a line of input is received.

To implement this kind of a timeout, it is necessary to use operating system-specific system calls to wait until either standard input is available, or a timer expires. This is outside the scope of the C++ standard.

Comment: "This is outside the scope of the C++ standard." What exactly is "this" that's outside the C++ standard? (a bit more complex, but one can implement the expected behaviour inside C++11 using std::thread, etc )

Comment: The thing I'm trying to achieve must be possible though because it is my assignment from a teacher lol. She showed us a demo and it is supposed to be pretty simple.

Comment: Well then, ask your teacher for assistance. I'm sure your teacher wouldn't ask you to write something without presenting the necessary material that's needed to complete the homework assignment.

Comment: The presence of `_kbhit` reveals a dependency on [MS libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx).

Comment: So does the [tag:visual-c++] tag.

Comment: @JasonC Which was added afterwards. By me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `cin >>` blocks and waits.

You have a couple options here, but the one that comes to mind is to roll your own thing with `_kbhit()`, which does not wait, and [`_getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx), e.g. pseudo code:

```
string inputStr = "";

while (elapsed time < time limit) {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        int ch = _getch();
        if ch is a carriage return then break;
        otherwise append ch to inputStr;
    }
}

int inputNumber = convert inputStr to an int;
```

Tweaking the logic as necessary depending on exactly what you're going for, but you get the idea.

Note: I'm not actually sure if this will work; please feel free to confirm or tear it apart in comments. I just can't test it right now. It's been a while since I used these functions and I'm not sure if `_getch()` will return immediately if there is input in the buffer, or if it will clear the buffer, or if some weird non-stdin console dependent thing, or what.